# Cannot apply custom gradle settings plugin to a settings.gradle in multi-project. Plugin with id '' not found, on a composite build

Tags: java, kotlin, gradle, gradle-plugin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I have a Gradle 8.1 project named `core` (It's a library, that will be published and used in other projects)

Inside the project, I have several modules (multi-project)

One of the modules is: `sanny-gradle-plugins`. It has a plugin

`sanny-gradle-plugins`: `eu.sanny.core.gradle.plugins.MyTestPlugin`

```kotlin
class MyTestPlugin : Plugin<Settings> {
    override fun apply(settings: Settings) {
        println("Hello sanny 1")
        println("Plugin ${this.javaClass.simpleName} applied on ${settings.rootProject.name}")
        settings.gradle.beforeProject {
            println("Hello sanny 2")
        }
    }
}
```

The plugin is intended to be used for the `core` multi-module library itself and later on in other projects that will be dependant on the `core` library

And `sanny-gradle-plugins/build.gradle.kts` file, looks like this:

```kotlin
plugins {
    `kotlin-dsl`
    `java-gradle-plugin`
    `maven-publish`
}

dependencies {
    implementation(kotlin("stdlib"))
    implementation(gradleApi())
}

gradlePlugin {
    plugins {
        create("my-test-plugin") {
            id = "my-test-plugin"
            displayName = "My Test Plugin"
            implementationClass = "eu.sanny.core.gradle.plugins.MyTestPlugin"
        }
    }
}
```

Also I have `resources/META-INF/gradle-plugins/my-test-plugin.properties` file (just in case):

```
implementation-class=eu.sanny.core.gradle.plugins.MyTestPlugin
```

I have a `settings.gradle.kts` file in the parent `core` project:

```kotlin
pluginManagement {
    includeBuild("sanny-gradle-plugins")
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
    }

    plugins {
        val springBootPluginVersion: String by settings
        val kotlinPluginVersion: String by settings

        id("my-test-plugin")
        kotlin("jvm") version kotlinPluginVersion
        kotlin("plugin.spring") version kotlinPluginVersion
        kotlin("plugin.jpa") version kotlinPluginVersion
    }

    // when I'm applying the plugin I'm getting an error
    apply(plugin = "my-test-plugin")

...
```

when I build the project I get an error: `Plugin with id 'my-test-plugin' not found.`

I've tried to put the `apply(plugin = "my-test-plugin")` before and inside the `pluginManagement` section as well - it does not help.

Why is this error happening and how to fix it?

Comment: Are you wanting to publish this plugin and share it with other projects that are not part of this code base, or are you wanting to use this plugin only among submodules of the same code base? I need to understand a bit more about your goals before I can make a good suggestion.

Comment: Hi, @GreenSaguaro, thanks for asking, I'm planning to do both, use it from the same code base, and publish it to use in other projects

Comment: For disclosure, I have not attempted to do this before, I usually publish a plugin, or use convention files. But you need to do both. One thing I see is that you are doing `apply(plugin = "my-test-plugin")`. This should not be necessary as `id("my-test-plugin")` should already be applying the plugin. What do you get if you remove `apply(plugin = "my-test-plugin")`?

Comment: Instead of specifying `my-test-plugin` inside of `pluginManagement { plugins {} }` instead add it in the top-level plugins block, i.e. `plugins { id("my-test-plugin") }`.

Comment: Thank you @GreenSaguaro! You are absolutely right, I've changed it to the `plugins {
 id("eu.sunny.gradle.plugins.my-test-plugin")
}` and it's enough to apply the plugin. Just as for now I'm using a pre-built plugin, `url = uri("file://${rootProject.projectDir}/sanny-gradle-plugins/build/repo")`, but I think even this is not needed. Will write the final working solutions later or

Comment: @AlexanderArutinyants So it is correctly applying the plugin when you remove `apply(plugin = "my-test-plugin")`?

Comment: Yes, @GreenSaguaro. So far with `plugins { id("my-test-plugin") }` and `pluginManagement {
    includeBuild("sanny-gradle-plugins") }` it seems to apply the plugin and work correctly...